# How to open and close browser in RFT

Tags: rft

I am new to RFT and i just want simple script to open browser and close the same using RFT.
I tried to find solution on internet but there were solutions which i can't digest.
Help me out on this

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to [enable your browser](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBLQQ_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.test.ft.doc/topics/RunHTMLEnabler.html). Then [configure your application](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBLQQ_8.7.1/com.ibm.rational.test.ft.doc/topics/ConfiguringAppsTesting.html). After that you can use the recorder to start your configured application (this starts the browser if it is a web application) and you can also use the recorder to record the close browser action.

For starting your browser the generated code will be something like this:

```
startApp("nameOfTheAppYouConfigured");
```

For closing:

```
browser_htmlBrowser(document_YourDocument(), MAY_EXIT).close();
```

BTW: What is so difficult in following a guide like [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/10/automateintegrationtestswithrationalfunctionaltester/) or just using the RFT tutorials...